# python starred expression assigned to multiple variables

Tags: python

I have this starred expression but it gives error `SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here` so any alternative solutions would be appreciated.

```
def checker(packages):
    for pac in packages:
        print(*pac)
        a,b,c=*pac
        return a,b,c
print(checker([[4,3,7],[9,6,1]]))
```

Comment: Replace `a,b,c=*pac` with `a,b,c=pac`. This is why tracebacks are important.

Comment: Even `a,b,c=[*pac]` should work fine.

Comment: Just a note, this is known as "sequence unpacking" or just "unpacking". You'll find more information by using that term.

Comment: finding terms are always tricky and a great part of solution, thanx beside giving answer you introduced the term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `*` :

```
a, b, c = pac
```

This is enough for python to unpack right hand side of the assignment.